# Passing first file in DIR command to a variable

Tags: batch-file

I want to pass the very first file returned by

```
dir *.png /B
```

into the variable %firstFile%

Comment: That's nice. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need `dir`?

```
for %%x in (*.png) do if not defined firstFile set "firstFile=%%x"
```

Answer (score 3):

why do you need to iterate over all of the list?

```
for  %%x in (*.*) do (
  set "firstFile=%%x"
  goto :done
)
:done
```

Answer (score 2):

shouldn't it be:

```
DIR *.png /B > "%TEMP%\dir" && SET firstFile= < "%TEMP%\dir"
```

Comment: please change to SET /p firstFile=< "%TEMP%\dir". So remove space and add /p. Works better.

Answer (score 0):

```
DIR *.png /B > "%TEMP%\dir" && < "%TEMP%\dir" SET firstFile=
```